# Как проще добавить скрипт в автозапуск Windows VBS

Tags: windows, vbscript

Нашел такой скрипт, который якобы добавляет сам себя в автозагрузку, если его нет в автозагрузке, а если есть, то не добавляет.

```vbscript
On Error Resume Next 
 NameScript = WScript.ScriptFullName 
 With WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
 RegScript = .RegRead("HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run\MyScript") 
 AddReg = True 
 If Err.Number <> 0 Then 
 Err.Clear 
 ElseIf RegScript = NameScript Then 
 AddReg = False 
 End If 
 If AddReg Then 
 .RegWrite "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run\MyScript", NameScript, "REG_SZ" 
 .Run "%systemroot%\System32\RUNDLL32.EXE user32.dll, UpdatePerUserSystemParameters", 0, True 
 End If 
End With
```

Потом подумал: "Проще же сделать так:"

```vbscript
Dim wshshell, fso
Set wshshell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

fso.CopyFile wscript.scriptfullname, wshshell.SpecialFolders("Startup")
```

Вроде бы имеет смысл, если к скрипту не привязаны никакие файлы из его же директории (`Left(wscript.scriptfullname, (Len(wscript.scriptfullname) - Len(wscript.scriptname)))`). Но если у меня по этому методу есть привязанные файлы, то сработает ли такой код правильно?

```vbscript
Dim wshshell, fso, link
Set wshshell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set link = wshshell.CreateShortcut(wshshell.SpecialFolders("Startup") & "prefs") 
link.TagretPath = wscript.scriptfullname
link.Description = "Link to application preferences file."
link.Save
wscript.quit
```

Comment: А почему бы лично не запустить и не проверить?

Comment: @Daemon-5  У меня нет на данный момент компа с Windows ☹️

Comment: Ну моно бесплатно напрокат у хостера взять погонять...Или любой доступный гипервизор установить

Answer (score 1):

Создайте еще два файла: s.bat и dir.vbs
VBS-файл:

```
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set F = FSO.GetFile(Wscript.ScriptFullName)

path = FSO.GetParentFolderName(F)
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set tf = fso.CreateTextFile("dir.txt", True)
tf.WriteLine path&"\НАЗВАНИЕ ВАШЕГО VBS ФАЙЛА.vbs"
```

ВАТ-файл:

```
start dir.vbs
timeout 1
Set /p pathBat=<dir.txt
Reg Add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run" /v "VBS" /t REG_SZ /d "%pathBat%" /f
```

Answer (score 1):

Немного добавлю. Запуск любого скрипта из Автозагрузки должен производится либо с правами админа, либо в политиках (домена, например) указано, что из этой папки можно с правами пользователя. Плюс к этому: первичный запуск Вашего скрипта производится из какого-то другого места и ему не хватит прав записать копию себя в Startup. А вот на предмет кода сделал бы так: проверка на отсутствие в Автозагрузке > вызов утилиты robocopy для копирования. Этот вариант, на мой взгляд, и короче и правильнее что ли.